# How can the Person object be extended in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have tried for a day or so to extend the person model with extra attributes and thus far, been un-successful. I followed [this old tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/02/27/1555) but couldn't get it working. A look at some of the replies on the page showed that someone had tried in 4.1 and didn't get it to work. I am testing against 4.2.
Any insight would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I have the following customContentModel.xml:

```
<model name="cm:contentModel" xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">
    <!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
    <description>Professional Person Model</description>
    <author></author>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <!-- Imports are required to allow references to definitions in other models -->
    <imports>
        <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d" />
        <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
        <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm" />

                <import uri="http://www.syn.fr/model/person/ext" prefix="ppm"/>
    </imports>

<types>
      <type name="cm:person">
         <title>Person</title>
         <parent>cm:authority</parent>
         <properties>
            <!-- The tokenisation set here is ignored - it is fixed for this type -->
            <!-- This is so you can not break person lookup -->
            <property name="cm:userName">
               <type>d:text</type>
               <mandatory>true</mandatory>
               <constraints>
                  <constraint ref="cm:userNameConstraint" />
               </constraints>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:homeFolder">
               <type>d:noderef</type>
               <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:firstName">
               <type>d:text</type>
               <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:lastName">
               <type>d:text</type>
               <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:middleName">
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:email">
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:organizationId">
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:homeFolderProvider">
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:defaultHomeFolderPath">
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:presenceProvider">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:presenceUsername">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:organization">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:jobtitle">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:location">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:persondescription">
                <type>d:content</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:telephone">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:mobile">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:companyaddress1">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:companyaddress2">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:companyaddress3">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:companypostcode">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:companytelephone">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:companyfax">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:companyemail">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:skype">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:instantmsg">
                <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:userStatus">
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:userStatusTime">
               <type>d:datetime</type>
            </property>
            <property name="cm:googleusername">
               <type>d:text</type>
            </property>

            <property name="cm:emailFeedDisabled">
                <type>d:boolean</type>
            </property>

            <property name="cm:subscriptionsPrivate">
                <type>d:boolean</type>
            </property>

            <!-- system maintained / protected values -->

            <property name="cm:emailFeedId">
                <type>d:long</type>
                <protected>true</protected>
            </property>

            <property name="cm:sizeCurrent">
                <type>d:long</type>
                <protected>true</protected>
                <mandatory enforced="true">true</mandatory>
            </property>

            <property name="cm:sizeQuota">
                <type>d:long</type>
                <protected>true</protected>
            </property>

         </properties>

         <associations>
            <association name="cm:avatar">
               <source>
                  <role>cm:avatarOf</role>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>false</many>
               </source>
               <target>
                  <class>cm:content</class>
                  <role>cm:hasAvatar</role>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>false</many>
               </target>
            </association>
         </associations>
      </type>

      <mandatory-aspects>
     <aspect>ppm:attributes</aspect>
      </mandatory-aspects>
</types>     
</model>
```

I get an error regarding the **cm:authority** saying it can not be found. surely all the cm:* namespace objects would've been loaded before the extensible ones and therefore the cm:authority itself would eb available?

Comment: Have you got it so that the extra properties are defined in the model and readable/writable in the repo / api? (That's the first step to do, before you start on the Share part!)

Comment: Still having trouble with this. I update my question.

Comment: I think your custom content model *must* have a unique name. Can you try changing it so that it doesn't clash with any of the built in Alfresco model files?

Comment: Not according to the second user in this post who seemed to have gotten away with it: http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/content-modeling/add-properties-user-model-08102009-0710 besides wouldn't that mean another model of the Person type would be created instead of just extending what was already there?

Comment: Your *type* will want to be `cm:person` if you're overriding the built-in one. It's the overall model name I think you need use a unique name for (i.e. not `cm:contentModel`)

Comment: I did this. I now think in doing so I will not extend the person object but rather a new person object will be created as the change in model name requires that I declare a new namespace (can't use the imported cm namespace) which isn't what I want. I will revert back to following the guidelines in the old 3.4 based post from the ecma architect site and hope that works.

Comment: ECM Architect = Jeff Potts, who does post here, so maybe he'll pop up and be able to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ECMA architect guide example worked. I downloaded the code example and adapted it to my situation.

Answer (score 3):

Really easy thing to do , just create your own type that extends cm:person and add your properties.

```
<type name="ab:myperson">
         <title>Person</title>
         <parent>cm:person</parent>
         <properties>
            <!-- The tokenisation set here is ignored - it is fixed for this type -->
            <!-- This is so you can not break person lookup -->
            <property name="ab:customField">
               <type>d:text</type>
               <mandatory>true</mandatory>
            </property>..
```

Problem is that this property will not be set on new user as they are not going to be of your desired type ab:myperson.

You need to create custom behaviour that will add your properties by changing the type of cm:person to ab:myperson.

Best solution would be to create aspect instead of custom type and with behaviour add your aspect and set properties.

Great tutorial on creating custom behaviours is

## http://alfrescoblog.com/2014/06/02/alfresco-creating-custom-behavior-tutorial/

This would be how to extend cm:person and work with it.